# Making future list items sortable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an input box for users to type in an item and then click the submit button or enter key and it is added to an unordered list with an id of sortable. I would like to make this user generated unordered list sortable using jQuery but I can't get it to work. I believe it involves the use of the on method but my attempts thus far have been completely unsuccessful.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Woost/ZHga5/) is the link to the jsfiddle containing the project.

Also, here is what I am linking to in the head of the html file:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Edit: On jsfiddle the list items are sortable but the enter key can't be used to submit and [object Object] is outputted rather than the input text. When opening the file in browser (chrome) it still is not sortable but the added list items do have the proper outputs.

Comment: where is the jQuery code you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just need to write `$('#listWish').val()` instead of `$('#listWish')`.

```
$("#submitButton").on("click", function(){
   $("#sortable").append('<li>' + $('#listWish').val() + '</li>').sortable("refresh");
});
```

Notice that I'm calling 'refresh' method after adding new item istead of reinializing whole list. For more information [read here](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh).

UPDATE:
It could be the case when you call `$("#sortable").sortable();` before your markup has been loaded. Try to make it this way:

```
$(function(){
   $("#sortable").sortable();
})
```

All code inside `$(function(){  })` wrapper will be called after all document is loaded.

Comment: This works on jsfiddle but I am still experiencing the same issues when I try and open my actual project file in the browser (chrome). It still will not allow me to sort the list items. I'm confused as to why there would be a difference between viewing it in jsfiddle and viewing it in the browser. Thanks for your contribution though!

Comment: Do you see any errors in console when you open your project file?

Comment: No errors in console. Originally I did get an error message saying file not found for each of the google hosted links in the head but after adding https: to the beginning of them it no longer gave me errors. Unfortunately, the list is still not able to be sorted.

Comment: Is any chance that you have two elements on the page with id="sortable"? What if you try to form some list inside #sortable ul, then call $("#sortable").sortable(); This way we could check if ui sortable plugin doesn't work at the initial page load or after adding some elements.

Comment: I formed a list inside #sortable ul and called $("#sortable").sortable(); in my script.js file and even that was not able to be sorted. Any ideas why it wouldn't work at the initial page load? There is definitely only one element with id="sortable". Thanks again for taking the time to respond.

Comment: I think it because jQuery-UI didn't load. Try to change https to http in google's cdns or try to download that files to your local machine and add to your project instead of using cdns.

Comment: This is odd. It seems to be loading yet the ability to sort still won't work. I tested if jQuery-UI loaded by adding the datepicker jQuery UI widget to my page and it worked perfectly. Any other ideas??

Comment: Wow, that was all that was needed to fix it. I feel like a fool. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This would be better if you do something like this

```
var changeText2 = function (){

    var listWish = $("#listWish").val();
    var node = $("#sortable").append("<li>")
    $("#sortable li:last-child").text(listWish);
    $("#sortable li").sort(naturalsort).appendTo("#sortable");

}
```

On JQuery [.append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/) append a child node to the selection and [.appendTo()](https://api.jquery.com/appendto/) append the selection contains, as child node, to an specific selection.

You can pass a function to the .sort() to specify how to sort the elements too.

Check my JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jkutianski/4PhxL/)

Comment: I doubt that CSS cause problems to JQuery code. Check the version of JQuery that you're loadind on JSFiddle.